# Drawable won't draw on SurfaceView, Thread implementation, without overriding onDraw

Tags: java, android, multithreading, drawable, surfaceview

I'm honestly stumped as to why this isn't working.  Trying to draw a simple PNG to the screen using a SurfaceView in the layout and a thread to draw rather than overriding the onDraw function.  It's essentially the exact same implementation as the LunarLander sample project (and I've practically ripped the entire codeset in frustration).

I've tested it via logs and I know that the sprite is being "drawn" to the canvas but nothing is showing up in the window.

Here's the code, hope it's not too lengthy (unimportant bits stripped out):

activity_pannenkoekenhuis.xml (layout/)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.pannenkoekenhuis.MainView
    android:id="@+id/pannenkoekenhuis_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Pannenkoekenhuis" >
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

MainView (SurfaceView):

```
public class MainView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

class MainThread extends Thread {
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Context context;
    Handler handler;

    HandleResources hResources;
    HandleGame hGame;

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context,
            Handler handler) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.context = context;
        this.handler = handler;
        hResources = new HandleResources(context);
        hGame = new HandleGame();

        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                            Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s_char);
                    d.draw(canvas);
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

MainThread thread;

public MainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    thread = new MainThread(surfaceHolder, context, new Handler());

    setFocusable(true);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just some friendly advice.  Your post is too long, it contains too much code and for that reason may not attract serious users.  If you can, reduce your problem statement substantially and cut your code down to a single paragraph with emphasis on a single line that isn't working as planned.

Comment: Thanks, edited most of it out.  Hopefully it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Gah, figured it out.  Needed to remove setBackgroundColor() for some reason as it was probably drawing over the graphics.  Stupid mistake.